# A Poincare-Miranda theorem for multivalued functions

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, multivalued-functions

The [Poincare-Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) is an extension of the intermediate value theorem to multi-dimensional functions. It is considered to be equivalent to [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).
Both these theorems deal with single-valued functions.

Now, Brouwer's theorem has a generalization - [Kakutani's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) - that deals with multi-valued (set-valued) functions.
So it is reasonable to expect that the Poincare-Miranda theorem has a generalization for multi-valued functions. 
Is there such a generalization?